# How to get the lists on the left?

Tags: html, css

```css
header {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: 10;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "GasoekOne-Regular";
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-left: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-link {
  align-items: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-main">
    <br>
    <h1 class="nav-logo nav-main">TENSTARLIGHT</h1>
    <div class="header-item nav-main">
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </header>

</div>
```

Most of the css code is just me trying to move it on the left.

So, I finally figure out how to create a navbar. The thing is that the Store, about, Contact Us is only going on the right but, I want it on the left and I cant find anything on it.

Comment: What do you mean by lists? The logo (aka "TENSTARLIGHT") or by lists you mean "Store", "About" and "Contact Us"? Edit the question to make It more clear.

Comment: I guess you want to put the menu in front of the title. You can solve the problem by typing the "h1" tag after the div class.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. Please explain and include an image, if possible.

Comment: So you want to put `flex-direction: row-reverse;` on `.nav-main` then, is that it? (FYI: List items belong into a list element (ul/ol), not just floating around in a div. And that `br` element really should not be in there, use CSS for margins/paddings.)

Comment: @timR So, You are correct with some of the unneeded css but the remove of margin auto on h1 is uncorrect, in fact, it made it worst. CBroe's comment on flex direction had help me because I want the h1 to stay in place but I just want the lists(Store,About,Contact Us) on the other side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the links are pushed to the right is the `margin-left: auto;` declartion for `h1` and `.nav-main`. In this snippet, I have commented out those two declarations:

```css
header {
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  text-align: center;
  margin-inline: 10;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "GasoekOne-Regular";
  font-size: 45px;
  /* margin-left: auto; */
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav-link {
  align-items: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-main">
    <br>
    <h1 class="nav-logo nav-main">TENSTARLIGHT</h1>
    <div class="header-item nav-main">
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item nav-main">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </header>

</div>
```

This snippet has an identical result after correcting the markup and removing the unneeded CSS declarations:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

nav h1 {
  font-family: "GasoekOne-Regular";
  font-size: 3em;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-inline: 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1>TENSTARLIGHT</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Store</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```